# Delete the last row in the last page LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, lazydatamodel

I have 21 records (N*10 + 1 records) and two pages, each page show max 10 records. When I delete the last record( It means the 1st record of the third page ), the browser will show the 2nd page with no record. If I want to see the record, I had to reload the browser. I want it load to the second page (the previous page). Do anyone have a solution for this? Im using LazyDataModel and JSF. I'm bad at English so sorry.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. My guess is that you forgot to update the row count using `yourLazyModel.setRowCount(...)`.

Comment: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=24475
I found one who had the same issue. And I tried setRowCount(), It didnt work

Comment: Oh sorry, It works . Thank you bro @Jasper de Vries